# Cassandra Updates not working properly

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

```
BoundStatement UpdateTable = new BoundStatement(preparedStatement);


UpdateTable.bind(productId, productname, time);

session.execute(UpdateTable);
```

I am using the following commands to update cassandra tables.Sometimes it updates and sometimes it doesn't.

`UPDATE  product SET count = count + 1 where productId = ? AND productname = ? AND time = ?;`

It never throws an error.

Why is this ?

**EDIT**

Table structure

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(productId int,productname text,time timestamp , count counter,PRIMARY KEY (productid,productname,time));`

Comment: How many nodes are there in cluster and what is the READ and WRITE consistency?

Comment: there is only `one` node in the cluster and `concurrent_reads: 32`,
`concurrent_writes: 32`,
`concurrent_counter_writes: 32`

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your (Java?) code, I can't really tell what kind of object `insertUpdateTable` is.  But the `bind` method should return a BoundStatement object that can be executed.  And while `UpdateTable` is indeed a BoundStatement, I don't see that you're actually binding your variables to it.

Based on the limited amount of code shown, I see two solutions here:

1. Call the `bind` method on `UpdateTable` inside your `session.execute`:

   session.execute(UpdateTable.bind(productId, productname, time));
2. Wrap your `insertUpdateTable.bind` inside a `session.execute`:

   session.execute(insertUpdateTable.bind(productId, productname, time));

Check out the DataStax documentation on [Using Bound Statements](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html) with the Java driver for more information.

> Sometimes it updates and sometimes it doesn't.

If you had posted your Cassandra table definition, it might shed some more light on this.  But it is important to remember that Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs are unique, and that `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s are essentially the same (an `INSERT` can "update" existing values and an `UPDATE` can "insert" new values).  Sometimes an `UPDATE` may appear to not work, when it may be performing a write with the same key values.  Just something to look out for.

Also important to note, is that `UPDATE  product SET count = count + 1` will only work under two conditions:

1. `count` is a counter column.
2. `product` is a counter table, consisting of only keys and counter columns (all non-counter columns *must* be a part of the PRIMARY KEY).

Worth noting is that counter columns [underwent a big change/improvement with Cassandra 2.1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters).  If you need to use counters and are still on Cassandra 2.0, it may be worth upgrading.

Comment: Have updated the question with table structure. This is a java code.As, I said it never throws any error. But, sometimes it works and some time it doesn't. Also, when i check logs i see the values there.I don't know what is happening.

Comment: @user4974500 The thing is, that you wouldn't see an error message, because everything is syntactically correct.  Does the system.log show any related messages at the times that you run the UPDATE?  If possible try running this on a 2.1 test cluster and see if your results are more-consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You said the update sometimes works, but note that if you ever delete row with a counter, you'll be unable to modify the row again without dropping the table and recreating it. The update will appear to fail silently. For more, see [CASSANDRA-8491](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8491)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue during high frequency writes & updates.

As the number of concurrent requests goes up, there is good chance that the latest bind may over write the previous bound params. So instead of using single boundStatement, used preparedStatement.bind() in the session.execute

Can you try the following.

Instead of using :

```
UpdateTable.bind(productId, productname, time);
 session.execute(UpdateTable);
```

Use :

```
session.execute(preparedStatement.bind(productId, productname, time));
```